# Fitting a polynomial surface to a 3D data Set

Tags: python, model-fitting

Is there a method to fit some function (representing some 2D surface) to a 3D data set?

I am making the assumption that the surface has degree 5 in one direction and degree 3 in the other direction.

So I would fit the function f(x,y) = [poly function] to some data sets X,Y, and Z.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `symfit` package might do the trick. It's a package I wrote which merges `scipy` with `sympy`. To solve your problem, I would do something like this:

```
from symfit import Poly, variables, parameters, Model, Fit

x, y, z = variables('x, y, z')
c1, c2 = parameters('c1, c2')
model_dict = {z: Poly( {(1, 2): c1, (4, 5): c2}, x ,y)}
model = Model(model_dict)
print(model)

>>> z(x, y; c1, c2) = Poly(c2*x**4*y**5 + c1*x*y**2, x, y, domain='ZZ[c1,c2]')
```

So in this case, I made polynomial with two coefficients, representing two terms of mixed order in `x` and `y`.

Now I can fit this polynomial to some data by using

```
fit = Fit(model, x=xmesh, y=ymesh, z=zdata)
fit_result = fit.execute()
```

Where xmesh and ymesh represent a meshgrid of your coordinates. Easy as pie!

Check out the [`symfit`](http://symfit.readthedocs.io) docs for more info, as well as the [`sympy`](https://docs.sympy.org/0.6.7/modules/polynomials.html#poly) ones for more info on Poly. Some fully functional example code of how to use a meshgrid with `symfit` can be found [here](https://github.com/tBuLi/symfit/blob/4ef619491a9979e1e3371047b23ba9739fa4207d/tests/test_auto_fit.py#L225).